# ¿Cómo Calcular cuando será el próximo año bisiesto?

Tags: c++

Tengo que hacer un programa que consiste en calcular cuando será el próximo año bisiesto dependiendo del año que ingrese en la consola. Pero siendo honesto, no se me ocurre nada para hacer el cálculo. Me gustaría que me ayudaran con este problema.

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada tienes que saber cuál es la formula para calcular el año bisiesto.

> Los años bisiestos son los divisibles entre 4 (como 2004, 2008, etc.) 
>   excepto si es divisible entre 100, entonces no es bisiesto (como 2100, 2200, etc.) 
>   excepto si es divisible entre 400, entonces sí (como 2000, 2400)

Basándonos en esto podemos hacer una condición:

```
if((anio % 4 == 0 && anio % 100 != 0) || anio % 400 == 0)
{
}
```

Teniendo esa condición lo único que tienes que hacer es hacer un ciclo para recorrer los años posteriores al ingresado hasta que cumpla esa condición.

```
int anio = anioIngresado;
while(true)
{
    if((anio % 4 == 0 && anio % 100 != 0) || anio % 400 == 0)
    {
        // año bisiesto
        break;
    }
    anio++;
}
```

Comment: Ya me funciona xD muchas gracias man pero tengo una pregunta cual son las funciones de break y anio++? osea porque se necesitan para hacer este programa? Si pudieras responder me ayudarías un montón ya que soy muy nuevo en programación en C++

Comment: Y me di cuenta que cuando pongo 2000 no imprime el siguiente año bisiesto pero sin embargo cuando pongo 2001 uno si me dice el siguiente año bisiesto, ¿porque pasa?

Comment: El `break` es para que cuando encuentre el año bisiesto se termine el ciclo y el `anio++` es una abreviación de `anio = anio + 1`, que lo único que hace es sumarle uno al valor que se tenía en la variable. No te regresa el siguiente año bisiesto porque el año 2000 es bisiesto y te está regresando ese mismo. Si quieres que ignore ese, tendrías que sumarle uno a la primera línea: `int anio = anioIngresado + 1;`.